# pyOpenGL texture not rendering

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, pyopengl

So I've been racking my brain with nonstop trial and error. I feel like I keep coming back with questions about the same thing and it is frustrating.

I am following the tutorials and looking at the C++ code and following along with Python trying to replicate the result. I've noticed there are subtle differences through trial and error and I've searched high and low on the internet to see if someone else has experienced my issue. 9/10 times it is because the texture was not bound, however, it my case it is.
https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer_gh.php?code=src/1.getting_started/4.1.textures/textures.cpp

So I am wondering what I am doing wrong... any help?

```
import os       # For mac... I am using a mac
import glfw     # We're using this instead of GLUT as we have more flexibility
import numpy as np    # We will use numpy for our arrays
# Using the API wrapper instead of something mugh higher. Keep in mind that the API is a state machine
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.arrays import *
from ctypes import c_void_p
from PIL import Image

class HelloWindow():

    width = 800
    height = 640
    title = 'Hello Window'
    window = None
    shader_program = None
    vao = None
    vbo = None
    texture = None

    vertex_gsl = """
        #version 410 core
        layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
        layout (location = 1) in vec3 aColor;
        layout (location = 3) in vec2 aTexCoord;

        out vec3 ourColor;
        out vec2 TexCoord;

        void main() {
            gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);
            ourColor = aColor;
            TexCoord = vec2(aTexCoord);
        }
    """

    fragment_gsl = """
        #version 410 core
        out vec4 FragColor;

        in vec3 ourColor;
        in vec2 TexCoord;

        uniform sampler2D texture1;

        void main() {
            FragColor = texture(texture1, TexCoord);
        }
    """

    def __init__(self):
        if not glfw.init():
            raise TypeError('Unable to initalize glfw')
        self.main()

    def main(self):
        # Set window hints
        self.set_window_hints()
        # Create the window
        self.create_window()

        max_vertex_attributes = glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS)
        print('Maximum number of vertex attributes in a vertex shader is: ' + str(max_vertex_attributes))

        # Keep the window open in a loop
        self.loop()

    def set_window_hints(self):
        glfw.window_hint(glfw.SAMPLES, 4)
        # Using the core version in Mac OS but can be set to something else
        glfw.window_hint(glfw.CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4)
        glfw.window_hint(glfw.CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 1)
        glfw.window_hint(glfw.OPENGL_PROFILE, glfw.OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE)
        glfw.window_hint(glfw.OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, True)

    def create_window(self):
        self.window = glfw.create_window(self.width, self.height, self.title, None, None)

        if not self.window:
            raise TypeError('Unable to create the window')
            glfw.terminate()

        glfw.make_context_current(self.window)
        glfw.set_framebuffer_size_callback(self.window, self.frame_buffer_size)


        ### Let's setup our data
        verts = np.array([
            # positions         # colors        # texture coords
            [-0.5, 0.5, 0.0,    1.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 1.0],
            [-0.5, -0.5, 0.0,   0.0, 1.0, 0.0,  0.0, 0.0],
            [0.5, -0.5, 0.0,    0.0, 0.0, 1.0,  1.0, 0.0],
            [0.5, 0.5, 0.0,     1.0, 1.0, 0.0,  1.0, 1.0]
        ], dtype=np.float32) # OpenGL expects 32 bit data. Not 64 bit if you're on a 64 bit machine

        indicies = np.array([
            [0, 1, 3],
            [1, 2, 3]
        ], dtype=np.uint32)

        self.vao = glGenVertexArrays(1)
        self.vbo = glGenBuffers(1)
        self.ebo = glGenBuffers(1)

        glBindVertexArray(self.vao)

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vbo) # Bind the buffer as an array buffer and not an element buffer
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verts, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.ebo)
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicies, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, False, 8 * verts.itemsize, None)
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)

        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, False, 8 * verts.itemsize, c_void_p(3 * verts.itemsize))
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1)

        glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, False, 8 * verts.itemsize, c_void_p(6 * verts.itemsize))
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2)

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)
        glBindVertexArray(0)

        self.setup_shader()

        self.texture = glGenTextures(1)
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.texture)
        glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)

        # Set the wrapping texture parameters for x,y equivalents
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT)
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT)

        # Set the texture filtering parameters from min to max
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR)
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)

        # Load our image
        img = Image.open('../res/container.jpg')
        img.transpose(Image.FLIP_TOP_BOTTOM)
        img.convert('RGB')
        data = np.array(list(img.getdata()), np.uint8)

        # Set the texture data
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, img.width, img.height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data)
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D)

        #img.close()

    def loop(self):
        while not glfw.window_should_close(self.window):
            glClearColor(0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 1.0)
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)    # We always use this after we clear the color

            # Maintain aspect ratio (optional)
            glfw.set_window_aspect_ratio(self.window, self.width, self.height)

            # Handle input
            self.capture_input()

            # Bind the texture
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.texture)

            # Do some rendering
            glUseProgram(self.shader_program)
            glBindVertexArray(self.vao)
            #glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
            #glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3)
            glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, None)

            glfw.swap_interval(1)
            glfw.swap_buffers(self.window)
            glfw.poll_events()

        glfw.destroy_window(self.window)

        # Add the vao and vbo to an array so they're deleted. We can use this when creating several vaos and vbos
        vao_list = np.array([self.vao], dtype=np.uint32)
        vbo_list = np.array([self.vbo], dtype=np.uint32)

        glDeleteVertexArrays(1, vao_list)
        glDeleteBuffers(1, vbo_list)
        glfw.terminate()

    def capture_input(self):
        if glfw.get_key(self.window, glfw.KEY_ESCAPE) == glfw.PRESS: # Get the key pressed and check if it is escape key
            glfw.set_window_should_close(self.window, True)

    def frame_buffer_size(self, window, width, height):
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height)

    def setup_shader(self):
        vertex_shader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
        glShaderSource(vertex_shader, self.vertex_gsl)
        glCompileShader(vertex_shader)

        if not glGetShaderiv(vertex_shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS):
            glGetShaderInfoLog(vertex_shader, 512, None)
            raise TypeError('vertex_shader did not compile correctly. Check the GSL')

        fragment_shader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
        glShaderSource(fragment_shader, self.fragment_gsl)
        glCompileShader(fragment_shader)

        if not glGetShaderiv(fragment_shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS):
            glGetShaderInfoLog(fragment_shader, 512, None)
            raise TypeError('fragment_shader did not compile correctly. Check the GSL')

        self.shader_program = glCreateProgram()
        glAttachShader(self.shader_program, vertex_shader)
        glAttachShader(self.shader_program, fragment_shader)
        glLinkProgram(self.shader_program)

        if not glGetProgramiv(self.shader_program, GL_LINK_STATUS):
            glGetProgramInfoLog(self.shader_program, 512, None)

        glDeleteShader(vertex_shader)
        glDeleteShader(fragment_shader)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    hello_window = HelloWindow()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the program the attribute index specified for the array of texture coordinates is **2**:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, False, 8 * verts.itemsize, c_void_p(6 * verts.itemsize))
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2)
```

But in the vertex shader the attribute index specified for the texture coordinates is **3**, by [Layout Qualifier](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Vertex_shader_attribute_index):

```
layout (location = 3) in vec2 aTexCoord;
```

Use the same attribute index in both cases and your texture will show up.